# Given $2n$ complex numbers ...

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $2n$ complex numbers $a_1, a_2,\ldots,a_n,b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$, where the numbers $a_j$ are all distinctt, show that there exist an unique polynomial $p(z)$ of degree $\leq n-1$ such that $$p(a_j)=b_j \quad \text{for all} \quad j=1$$

I am stuck in trying to start this problem I can see what is going on conceptually but I do not know how to start the proof. I think there is some trick or theorem I am not using to prove it.

Comment: Minor check: "for all $j=1$" would be "for all $1\le j\le n$", correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lagrange's interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) gives one such polynomial. Take two different polynomials $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ of degree at most $n - 1$ satisfying the requirements, then the polynomial $p(z) - q(z)$ has degree at most $n - 1$ and has $n$ zeros, so it is identically zero.

The last because if the polynomial $P(z)$ has a zero at $a$, $z - a$ divides $P(z)$. If a polynomial of degree at most $n - 1$ has $n$ zeros, it is divisible by the $n$-th degree polynomial $(z - a_1) \dotsm (z - a_n)$, and that is only possible if the polynomial is zero.